# Subjunctive I for recommendation?

Tags: grammar, subjunctive

> Wer sich die Fotos zu Hause anschauen möchte, dem sei der Ausstellungskatalog empfohlen.

Why is the Subjunctive I "sei" used here? Is it to make a recommendation?

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: [Subjunctive I in “Man denke beispielsweise an die Integration rationaler Funktionen”](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/9060/2594)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one can call "sei empfohlen" a subjunctive for recommendation. The writer might have written, "dem empfehle ich" - the most normal expression - or "dem möchte ich empfehlen". With "sei empfohlen" the writer expresses in an elevated style his suggestion. This formulation is elevated written style.

Answer (score 1):

**Why is the subjunctive used here?**

It is just a way to support the meaning of a recommendation. You could also use #1 or #2 from the list below. I wouldn't use option #3 since it sounds a bit weird.

> 1) Wer sich die Fotos zu Hause anschauen möchte, dem ist der Ausstellungskatalog zu empfehlen.
>
> 2) Wer sich die Fotos zu Hause anschauen möchte, dem wird der Ausstellungskatalog empfohlen.
>
> 3) Wer sich die Fotos zu Hause anschauen möchte, dem ist der Ausstellungskatalog empfohlen.

**Is it to make a recommendation?**

The sentence obtains the sense of a recommendation mainly from the verb `empfohlen`. Obviously, the conjunctive mood does not make much sense without an appropriate verb.
However, I would say that it supports the meaning of a recommendation to some notable extent.

---

It is called *Konjunktiv*, not subjunctive. (Although they are similar, they are not the same<sup>1, 2</sup>).

1: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konjunktiv#Der_Konjunktiv_I
2: http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Subjunktiv

Comment: I thought the English word for *Konjunktiv* [was actually  *subjunctive*](http://www.dict.cc/?s=konjunktiv&=DEEN&=). And in which sense does your answer address the question?

Comment: @c.p. 1. [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=konjunktiv) does translate *Konjunktiv* to *subjunctive*, but also to *conjunctive mood*. I'm open to more reliable references than Wikipedia. 2. The OP asked why the subjunctive is being used here. I answer the question insofar that I state that indicative can also be used. I think this is the point which confused the OP.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "wird" instead "ist"? »Wer sich die Fotos zu Hause anschauen möchte, dem **wird** der Ausstellungskatalog empfohlen.« Or: »... dem ist der Ausstellungskatalog **zu empfehlen**.«

Comment: @HubertSchölnast I admit it does sound a bit weird and strange, but not totally wrong. I now included your examples as better alternatives (if you don't mind).

Comment: @c.p. Yes, you're right. The German word "Konjunktiv" is translated with "subjunctive". The English word "[conjunctive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conjunctive)" is a false friend. "Subjunktiv" in German isn't quite used but it would mean the same thing.

Comment: As far as I know–but I might be totally wrong on that–German doesn't have something like a "real" subjunctive. Such a subjunctive exists in the Spanish language ([Subjuntivo](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjuntivo)). The German Konjunktiv does not exist in Spanish. – However, both are not too different and are often (incorrectly) considered equal.

Comment: @Em1 I agree. *Konjunktiv* and Spanish subjunctive are in essence the same. Difference are e.g. "...,damit du schwimmen kannst" needs subjunctive in Spanish ("para que (tú) *puedas* nadar"; it's mandatory and only little children say instead "para que (tú) *puedes* nadar", which is plain wrong); on the other hand, for us in Spanish the use of subjunctive in reported speech is only optional (expresses some doubt on the statements one is reproducing), while in German I perceive it as mandatory (maybe only in written German, I'm not quite sure).

Answer (score 1):

Es handelt sich um die gleiche Bedeutung des Wortes "sei" wie bei einem Segensspruch: z.B. heißt es "Friede sei mit dir" und nicht "Friede ist mit dir". Das Wort "sei" impliziert einen zeitlichen Verlauf. Der Gesegnete ist gesegnet, nachdem der Segen ausgesprochen wurde und nicht vorher. Es macht also einen Unterschied, ob man den Segen ausspricht oder nicht. Das unterscheidet ihn von einer reinen Aussage (wie etwa "Friede ist mit dir".)

In diesem Fall: bevor ich höre, dass mir der Ausstellungkatalog empfohlen wird, ist er mir nicht empfohlen. Dann sagt jemand zu mir, dass mir der Ausstellungskatalog empfohlen sei. Und jetzt hat mir jemand den Ausstellungskatalog empfohlen.

Wenn jemand zu mir sagt: "der Ausstellungskatalog ist dir empfohlen", dann ist das eine reine Behauptung, die unabhängig davon wahr (oder falsch) ist, ob ich sie gehört habe oder nicht. Und es hört sich außerdem seltsam an für meine Ohren.

Im konkreten Fall ist "es sei dir der Ausstellungskatalog empfohlen" im Grunde gleichbedeutend mit "ich empfehle dir den Ausstellungskatalog" oder "wir empfehlen dir den Ausstellungskatalog". (Sprachtechnisch ist es nicht ganz dasselbe, aber das ist meiner Meinung nach Haarspalterei.) Die erste Variante mit "sei" wird gewählt, weil sie objektiver klingt.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for 'sei' is the same reason why this

> 3) Wer sich die Fotos zu Hause anschauen möchte, dem ist der
>   Ausstellungskatalog empfohlen.

is not a correct sentence. "Sei" is the conjunctive form of "ist". If you use it like above, you would say whoever want to see the pictures got the recommendation **in the past**. But the catalogue is a future possibility, in other words conjunctive.

btw. there is no subjunctive in the german language

Comment: You didn't read the comments to the other answer. You should also take a look at a recent question regarding [subjunctive](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/11947/1224). The word "conjunctive" in English means something entirely different and is a false friend with German "Konjunktiv". The grammatical mood "Konjunktiv" is expressed with the word "subjunctive" in English. That is, in the German language there **is** a subjunctive, although it's different (if similar) to the Spanish "subjuntivo". If you really want to go with "conjunctive", I'd recommend saying "conjunctive mood" at least.