# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen einem Subjunktiv und dem Konjunktiv?

Tags: subjunctive, terminology

In dieser Frage war von einem „Subjunktiv“ die Rede: [Subjunctive I for recommendation?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11939/subjunctive-i-for-recommendation)

Dort entstand Verwirrung um die Begriffe „Subjunktiv“ und „Konjunktiv“. Ich habe etwas recherchiert und dabei Folgendes herausgefunden:

- Die deutsche Sprache kennt keinen Subjunktiv, nur den Konjunktiv (diesen aber gleich in zwei verschiedenen Varianten).
- Der Subjunktiv ist etwas Ähnliches wie der Konjunktiv aber nicht genau dasselbe.
- Den Begriff “conjunctive” gibt es in der englischen Grammatik nicht. Die Konstruktion, die auf Deutsch „Konjunktiv“ genannt wird, heißt auf Englisch offenbar “subjunctive”.

Daher meine Fragen:

1. Was genau ist der Subjunktiv?
2. Was unterscheidet den Subjunktiv vom Konjunktiv?
3. Ist das, was auf Englisch “subjunctive” genannt wird, ein Subjunktiv oder ein Konjunktiv?

Was mich verwirrt: Die englische Wikipediaseite über den Subjunktiv stellt ihn ausdrücklich mit dem deutschen Konjunktiv gleich. Die sehr rudimentäre deutsche Wikipediaseite behauptet aber, dass nur eine Ähnlichkeit zwischen den beiden grammatischen Moden besteht, und nennt nur drei Sprachen, in denen es einen Subjunktiv gibt, nämlich Arabisch, Französisch und Spanisch. Weder Deutsch noch Englisch wären demnach Sprachen mit einem Subjunktiv.

Ich konnte nicht herausfinden, ob es Sprachen gibt, die sowohl den Subjunktiv als auch den Konjunktiv kennen.

Comment: Wenn du dich auf den deutschen Konjunktiv beziehst und ihn auf Englisch ausdrücken möchtest, ist es der subjunctive. Mit der englischen Grammatik kenne ich mich nur bedingt aus, und der deutsche Konjunktiv unterscheidet sich definitiv vom Englischen "subjunctive", daher mag ich nichts über die Definition subjunctive bzgl. des Englischen sage. Klar ist nur, dass im Spanischen (c.p. kann bestimmt näher drauf eingehen) nochmal von etwas anderem die Rede ist, wenn gleich auch ähnlich. ... to be continued

Comment: ...Im Deutschen gibt es keinen Subjunktiv. D.h. bzgl. der deutschen Grammatik, dass es keinen Unterschied zw. Subjunktiv und Konjunktiv gibt, da ersteres als (schlechte) Übersetzung für den eigentlichen Konjunktiv dienen kann. Das englische subjunctive ist im Bezug auf dt. Grammatik immer der Konjunktiv. Im Bezug auf spanischer Grammatik denke ich (ich weiß es nicht), ist es immer der Subjunktiv.

Comment: Oft deckt sich die Verwendung, jedoch nicht immer: Qiero, que te vayas. (Sub) // Ich will, dass du gehst. (Ind)

Comment: Ella dice, que la comida está rica. (Ind) // Sie sagt, das Essen sei gut. (Kon I)   Ähnliches findet man im Französischen vor.

Comment: Weil es so schön passt: [Pigor & Eichhorn - Subjonctif](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBgv_O4PZaQ).

Answer (score 3):

Im Deutschen heißt der Modus Konjunktiv, im Französischen gebraucht man den Ausdruck subjonctif und auch im Englischen spricht man von subjunctive. Es ist jeweils der gleiche Modus gemeint, wenn auch in den drei Sprachen der Konjunktiv unterschiedlich gebraucht wird. Es wäre falsch anzunehmen, dass es neben Indikativ und Konjunktiv noch einen dritten Modus gäbe. Es handelt sich nur um zwei verschiedene Namen für die gleiche Sache, wie das in Grammatik leider oft der Fall ist.

Der französische Begriff subjonctif – Modus der Unterordnung – betont die Tatsache, dass manche konjunktivische Nebensätze eigentlich nur die Unterordnung des Nebensatzes bezeichnen. Ein Name, der nur einen kleinen Teil der französischen Konjunktivverwendungen abdeckt. Der deutsche Begriff Konjunktiv meint im Grunde auch nichts anderes. Lateinisch conjungere heißt verbinden, und Nebensätze sind mit dem Hauptsatz verbunden, wenn sie auch nicht alle im Konjunktiv stehen. Im Grunde sind beide Begriffe nur traditionelle Bezeichnungen, die aber über die Verwendung dieses Modus sehr wenig besagen.

Comment: "Es wäre falsch anzunehmen, dass es neben Indikativ und Konjunktiv noch einen dritten Modus gäbe" -> Gibt es aber doch. Der nennt sich Imperativ. Und in anderen Sprachen gibt's noch weitere Modi, zum Beispiel den Optativ.

Comment: Ach ja, es gibt noch Imperativ und im Griechischen sogar noch einen Optativ. Ich rede aber nur vom Konjunktiv und ob es da vielleicht noch eine zweite Art von Konjunktiv gibt, wie Wikipedia vermuten läßt.Das ist aber nur Begriffsverwirrung von Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

> Würde es den Subjunktiv in der deutschen Sprache geben, dann hätte er in diesem Satz seinen
>   Platz.

Im Deutschen gibt es ihn aber nicht als eigenständige Form. Wo man im Spanischen für den Satz oben den Subjunktiv verwendet, wird im Deutschen eine Form des Konjunktivs genutzt.

Um das nochmal zu verdeutlichen: Im Deutschen verwendet man den Konjunktiv für die indirekte Rede oder für hypothetische Situationen. Ein echter Subjunktiv, wie z.B. der französische, wird nur für hypothetische Situationen genutzt, die sich dann aber z.B. auch als Wunsch äußern können. Ein Beispiel dafür wären Sätze wie "Ich möchte, dass...".

Die deutschen Erklärungen dazu sind ziemlich ungenau, aber in den Erklärungen in anderen Sprachen (französischer [Subjonctif](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjonctif), spanischer [Subjunctivo](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjuntivo)) erfährt man etwas mehr zum Subjunktiv.

Im Italienischen gibt es ihn auch, aber dort ist er im Gegensatz zum Französischen nicht obligatorisch.

Die bisher ausführlichste Beschreibung habe ich [in diesem Buch gefunden](http://books.google.de/books?id=DcI-4dBJtJwC&lpg=PA149&ots=3CIVu62y47&dq=Subjunktiv%20sprachen&hl=de&pg=PA149#v=onepage&q&f=false) gefunden. Auch wenn es nur ein Buch über gaskognisches Okzitanisch ist. Ich rate einfach mal, das ist auch eine Sprache, klingonischer Dialekt oder so...

Comment: Es ist umstritten ob Gaskonisch eine eigene Sprache ist oder ob es ein Dialekt der Sprache Okzitanisch ist. Es handelt sich aber in jedem Fall um eine galloromanische Sprache, also um eine romanische Sprache, die sich aus der Sprache der frühen Gallier entwickelt hat. Zu dieser Sprachfamilie gehört auch Französisch. Gaskognisches Okzitanisch ist also mit Französisch verwandt und kein klingonischer Dialekt.

Answer (score 1):

Bei den zwei Wörtern handelt es sich um *ein* Konzept - die Motivation des Gebrauchs deckt sich nämlich größtenteils:

Es geht um Ausdruck von Möglichkeit, Ungewissheit, Wünschen, Spott usw...

Ich würde kleinen Abweichungen (s. o.), die sich im Sprachgefühl kaum manifestieren, nicht allzu viel Gewicht zuschreiben. Letztendlich liegt der Unterschied damit in der **Sprache**, und nicht in dem Wort.

Comment: Im Französischen wird der Konjunktiv erheblich anders gebraucht als im Deutschen.

Comment: Die Abweichungen beziehen sich auf die *Motivation* des Gebrauchs, nicht auf die explizite Grammatik (eines Satzes).

Answer (score 1):

Abgesehen von der wirklich grundlegenden Begriffen wie **Verb, Substantiv** oder **Präsens** hat jede Sprache für jeden aus dem Lateinischen importierten Grammakikbegriff ihre eigene Definition. Deutsche Modalverben sind anders definiert als Englische, das gleiche gilt für **"transitiv"** und **"Adverb"**. Das Englische **"gerund"** hat wenig mit dem Französischen **"gérondif"** zu tun.

Daher kann man streng genommen KEINE Übersetzung solcher Begriffe vornehmen, denn erstens stimmt es stimmt nie und zweitens kommt es dann auch nch drauf an, welche Definition man innerhalb einer Sprache verwendet. Es gibt verschiedene Definitionen für "transitiv" in Deutsch.

Der Konjunktiv, wenn man denn unbedingt einen Namen sagen will, ist im Englischen einfach "the German Konjunktiv" and so on. Und im Unterricht kann man dann sagen, er ist so ungefähr WIE der subjunctive und das wars.

Was ist also der Unterschied? Es gibt keinen "Subjunktiv". Es gibt nur "Englisch subjunctive", "Italienisch subjuntivo" und so weiter.

Comment: Ich denke, hier werden zwei Kategorien vermischt: syntaktisch und semantisch. Die syntaktische Terminologie ist an die semantische Verwendung angelehnt, was jedoch nur eine grobe Approximation ist.

Answer (score 0):

Wenn man entsprechende Formen in Latein, Deutsch und Französisch vergleicht, zum Beispiel die Formen von lateinisch esse, sein,  sieht man dass die Formen zusammenhängen:

Lat. est - sit, 
Frz. il est - il soit/qu'il soit,
Dt. er ist - er sei

Die Konjunktivformen sit/soit/sei hängen historisch zusammen und bedeuten auch das gleiche, egal ob man das im Dt. Konjunktiv oder im Frz. subjonctif nennt.

Dass diese Formen im Französischen anders verwendet werden als im Deutschen hat nichts mit der unterschiedlichen Bezeichnung zu tun. Französisch hat den ganzen Konkunktiv-Ballast des Lateinischen bewahrt und leidet heute noch an einer "Konjunktiv-Krankheit", während im Deutschen der Konjunktiv doch auf ein Minimum beschränkt ist.