# Ein gewisser Unterschied zwischen Indikativ und Konjunktiv I

Tags: usage, phrase, sentence-structure

Wo liegt der Unterschied zwischen den folgenden Sätzen? Werden solche Strukturen für gewöhnlich benutzt?

> Wer das will, der **wählt** am 25. Mai  ZZZ!

> Wer das will, der **wähle** am 25. Mai  ZZZ!

<sub>"das" steht für eine politische Agenda; ZZZ steht für eine Partei.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

Der Konjunktiv wird hier als eine Art [Imperativ an die dritte Person Singular](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/9067/2594) genutzt.

> Wer […], der [Konjunktiv Ⅰ].

can be regarded as a fixed sentence construction in German.

Wäre der Satz an die zweite Person Singular oder die dritte Person Plural (Höflichkeitsform) gerichtet, würde er lauten:

> Wenn Du das willst, wähle am 25. Mai ZZZ!
>   Wenn Sie das wollen, wählen Sie am 25. Mai ZZZ!

Es gibt einige stilistische Gründe, derartige Texte nicht direkt an den Leser zu richten (ob dies gute Gründe sind, sei dahingestellt). Und in diesem Fall ist die archaische Verwendung des Konjunktivs eine Möglichkeit, eine Verbindung zum Wahlverhalten aufzubauen, die nicht allzu bestimmend wirkt. Die Verwendung des Indikativs entspräche nämlich Folgendem:

> Wenn Du das willst, wählst Du am 25. Mai ZZZ!

Answer (score 2):

Beide Varianten fordern auf, jedoch auf verschiedene Weise:

1. Es wird als Tatsache dargestellt, dass Personen, die "das" wollen, ZZZ wählen,
   *obwohl* die Wahl noch gar nicht war.

   Durch diese Formulierung sollen sich manche Personen dazu verpflichtet fühlen,
   diese Gleichsetzung zu erfüllen.
2. Diese Variante kann mit "möge wählen" umschrieben werden, und wird als "Jussiv" bezeichnet.
   Damit können Forderungen an die 3. Person ergehen.

   Sie ist nicht so direkt wie die erste, klingt aber ein bisschen archaisch. In gesprochener Sprache kaum noch zu finden.

Im Zusammenhang mit Wahlen findet man solche Strukturen eher, aber gerade in diesem Zusammenhang wirken beide polemisch.

Comment: Die Bezeichnung des Konjunktivs als Möglichkeitsform ist durchaus umstritten und meines Erachtens verwirrend. Zwar drückt der Konjunktiv häufig keine Tatsachen aus, dies ist aber eine Konsequenz seiner eigentlichen Funktion – wie auch im Beispielsatz, wo der Konjunktiv eine Aufforderung ausdrückt, welche natürlich überflüssig wäre, wenn das, wozu aufgefordert wird, schon in Stein gemeißelt wäre. Genausogut könnte man den Imperativ als *Möglichkeitsform* bezeichnen.

Comment: Da es sich hier um einen Iussiv handelt, ist die Bezeichnung natürlich nicht astrein. Meistens aber drückt er Ungewisses aus, also Mögliches. (Sie sagt, es sei...) Auch den Konjunktiv II verwendet man meistens, um (Un)mögliches auszudrücken. Wo findet diese Diskussion statt?

Comment: Worüber man tatsächlich streiten könnte, ist die Nomenklatur bzw. Klassifizierung all der verschiedenen Modi. Zum Beispiel, dass der Iussiv zum Imperativ gehören sollte a.s.

Comment: [Hier](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/optativ-potentialis-konjunktiv.php) wird das Thema zum Beispiel besprochen, wenn auch keine Diskussion stattfindet. Nach meinen Recherchen wird der Begriff hauptsächlich von Deutschbüchern und Leuten, die durch diese inspiriert werden, aber nicht von Germanisten verwendet. Vor allem aber ist mir kein Argument für die *Möglichkeitsform* bekannt, also ein Satz, in dem der Konjunktiv direkt eine Möglichkeit ausdrückt. Auch in »Sie sagt, es sei …« wird der Konjunktiv wegen der indirekten Rede verwendet, die Möglichkeit ist nur Nebeneffekt.

Comment: Ich zaudere noch, ob ich hier mal nach einem Gegenbeispiel fragen soll. Nur wie stelle ich das an, ohne dutzende falsche Antworten oder gar eine Diskussion zu provozieren?

Comment: Etwa in Konstruktionen wie: "Das könnte so sein". Der Artikel scheint sehr lang zu sein, ich lese ihn mir die Tage durch und melde mich, falls mir etwas Sinnvolles einfällt. (falls Lust -> Chat)

Answer (score 1):

The first one is a statement about what people do who want "that". It can be read as an appeal to vote if you want that but that is not explicit.

> People who want that vote for ZZZ.

The second one IS an appeal. It is not a real order but not a recommendation like "kann wählen" either.

> People who want that shall/may vote for ZZZ.