# Use of Konjunktiv I in "es sei denn, ..."

Tags: subjunctive

> Früher hatte das Wort „Streber“ die Bedeutung von „Widersacher“, „Gegner“. Dann wurde es für Beamte verwendet, die Karriere machen wollten. Später übernahmen es Studenten und Schüler. Streber helfen manchmal Mitschülern und lassen sie zum Beispiel die Hausaufgaben abschreiben. Sie hoffen, sich dadurch beliebter zu machen. Nur, wenn im Sportunterricht zwei Mannschaften aufgestellt werden, steht der Streber trotzdem immer als Letzter da. Es **sei** denn, es sind Mannschaften, die nur aus Strebern bestehen.

Why is "sei" used here? It is not indirect speech, and neither is it an instruction for someone to follow.

Comment: "Es sei denn" -> "unless", "except". – It introduces a specific situation where the preceding statement is not true. "The grind will always be the last person, except everyone is a grind." Funny enough that even then a grind will be the last one. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Es sei denn* is an almost if not fully [fossilised expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fossilization_(linguistics)) which originated when our vocabulary was different and which somehow survived. Therefore, you cannot understand it with today’s German alone (compare with the English *all of a sudden*). Thus, as a language learner, the best way to deal with it is learning it like a vocabulary.

As for the origin of the expression, it is related to the archaic meaning of *denn* (adverb):

> ausgenommen, wenn; unter der Voraussetzung, dass ([Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/denn_Adverb))
>   apart from; under the assumption, that

I am however not familiar enough with this to make any qualified statements about this.

<sup>My best guess so far is that *es sei* works as *let … be* ([as in Mathematics](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/1756/2594)) and thus the whole phrase translates to “let the case that … be exempt (from the above)”. However, this would use *denn* as a predicative adjective and not an adverb, so it does not really fit.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In Middle High German, Konjunktiv Präsens (I) was used differently; (Jaeckh 2011) mentions "goal-oriented contexts (wishes, demands, intentions)" or potentiality (page 11).

Some of this has survived, like commands:

> Wer noch Karten will, *melde* sich. (jussive mood)
>   *Seien* Sie vorsichtig! (jussive mood used as imperative)
>   *Seien* wir nicht so streng! (adhortative mood)

Wishes:

> Er ruhe in Frieden

Potentiality:

> Es sieht so aus, als *seien* sie überhastet aufgebrochen.

(after "als" you can use Konjunktiv Präsens or Präteritum (II))

"Es sei denn" apparently survived from older times as an idiom; translated to today's use of Konjunktiv, it would be:

> Ich möchte Dich ins Kino einladen, es *wäre* denn, Du willst nicht.

That she might not want to, is a potential event.

Literature:
Jaeckh, Karoline: Konjunktiv I - Synchronie und Diachronie, Stauffenburg Verlag, 2011.

Comment: Can you also explain why a whole phrase is used for this, i.e., why it’s not “[…], Du wollest denn nicht.” instead of “[…], es sei denn, Du willst nicht.”? Or from another point of view: Why the expletive construction (*es* + sein)?

Comment: "es sei denn" just means "unless". "I want to invite you to see a movie, *unless* you don't want to". The "sei" cannot be replaced by another Konjunktiv I, the construction is idiomatic.

Comment: I know all that (see my answer), but where does it come from?

Answer (score -1):

Der Konjunktiv kann vieles ausdrücken, indirekte Rede, hypothetische Annahmen wie in der Mathematik: A sei eine fixe/variable Größe. "Es sei denn, dass" könnte man etwa herleiten mit: Außer wir nehmen an, A sei B.

Ein typisches Beispiel für eine hypothetische Annahme ist etwa:

Nehmen wir ein mal an, die Erde sei keine Kugel, sondern eine flache Scheibe.

Wir wissen, dass die Erde nicht flach ist, aber wir können uns diesen Fall in Gedanken vorstellen und überlegen, welche Konsequenzen sich daraus ergäben.

Comment: In »Nehmen wir einmal an, die Erde sei keine Kugel […]« steht der der Konjunktiv nicht wegen der hypothetischen Annahme, sondern wegen der Abhängigkeit zu *annehmen* (wie indirekte Rede). Der Konjunktiv in mathematischen Annahmen (die man normalerweise nicht als Hypothesen bezeichnet), hat auch [andere Gründe](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/1756/2594).