# Welchen Modus kann das Wort „sei“ haben?

Tags: grammar, subjunctive

Mir ist klar, dass das „sei“ in Sätzen wie „Sei ruhig.“ ein Imperativ ist.

Allerdings taucht das Wort auch in Sätzen auf, in denen man es (zumindest umgangssprachlich) mit „wäre“ ersetzen könnte: „Er sagte, ich sei sehr aufgeweckt.“

Eine weitere Möglichkeit ist in mathematischen Beweisen. Oft fangen Sätze an mit „Sei x eine reelle Zahl“.

Welche Modi hat „sei“ in den angegebenen Fällen? Gibt es noch mehr Arten und Weisen, das Wort zu verwenden, und wenn ja, in welchem Modus?

Comment: Stichwort Konjunktiv. Und eine Flexionstabelle hilft: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:sein

Comment: Falls Du noch Fragen zur Benutzung des Konjunktivs hast, kannst Du diese separat fragen.  Schau aber vorher, ob sie nicht vielleicht Duplikate wären, zum Konjunktiv in der Mathematik und in Kochrezepten hatten wir schon Frage.

Comment: Ähnliche [Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/1756/1696) zum mathematischen Aspekt.

Answer (score 7):

In der deutschen Sprache gibt es die drei reflektierenden Verbmodi `Indikativ (Wirklichkeitsform)`, `Konjunktiv (Möglichkeitsform)` und `Imperativ (Befehlsform)`. „sei“ kommt im `Indikativ` *nicht* vor.

Im `Konjuktiv` `(Tempus Präsens)` tritt "sei" in der `1. und 3. Person` `Numerus Singular` auf.

> **„Er sagte, ich sei sehr aufgeweckt.“**
>
> „Er sagte, er sei sehr aufgeweckt.“

Im `Imperativ` tritt „sei“ in der `1., 2. und 3. Person` `Numerus Singular` auf.

> **„Sei ruhig!“** /  „Sei Du ruhig!“
>
> „Sei er ruhig!“
>
> „Sei ich ruhig!“

Die Imperativformen sind außer in der 2. Person Singular und Plural ( „du/ihr“ ) sowie der von der 3. Person entlehnten Höflichkeitsform („Sie“) im deutschen Sprachgebrauch sehr ungewöhnlich geworden. Deshalb wird fälschlich auch häufig gelehrt, der Imperativ *existiere* nur in der 2. Person (Höflichkeitsform eingeschlossen). In der Hofsprache vergangener Zeiten sind noch Sätze zu finden wie:

> Entferne er sich!
>
> Schweige er!
>
> Sei er folgsam!

Eine etwas gebräuchlichere Form außerhalb der typischen Lehrbuchfälle, die im Gebrauch wenig als Imperativ wahrgenommen wird (es sehr wohl aber im Sinne einer Aufforderung ist!), ist z.B.:

> Gehen wir ins Kino!

Beispiel für den Imperativ in der 1. Person Singular:

> Soll ich heute einkaufen? Ach was! Mache ich das morgen!

Das Beispiel mathematischer Sätze: **„Sei *x* eine reelle Zahl“**, kann auch ausgedrückt werden als: „Gegeben ist: *x* soll eine reelle Zahl sein.“ Das steht klar im *Imperativ*. Es wird nicht gesagt, dass dem *immer* so sei oder es so sein *könne*. Es ist eine *Definition* für den konkret vorliegenden Fall.

Comment: Bin mir nicht sicher, ob die Verwendung in der Mathematik "klar Imperativ" ist - Könnte durchaus Konjunktiv sein ("angenommen, dass")

Comment: Einen echten Imperativ gibt es nur in der zweiten Person.

Comment: Statt "Möglichkeitsform" wäre die Darstellung als "indirekte Rede" m.E. besser.

Comment: @userunknown Ich denke, "Möglichkeitsform" ist in dem Kontext korrekt gewählt, weil die indirekte Rede umfassender ist als der reine Konjunktiv. Die indirekte Rede ist auch im Indikativ in Verbindung mit der Konjunktion "dass" zulässig und existiert auch noch in Form von Infinitivsätzen: "Er behauptet, es nicht gewusst zu haben." Der deutsche Terminus "Möglichkeitsform" grenzt den Konjunktiv von den weiteren Formen indirekter Rede ab. Ind./Konj.: "Er behauptet, dass er es nicht gewusst hat / habe."

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone: Es geht doch ums Sein, nicht ums Haben. :) "Er behauptet, er sei es nicht (gewesen)."

Comment: @userunknown Es war ein Beispiel, das Verb spielt doch gar keine Rolle. "Er behauptet, es nicht gewesen zu sein. Er behauptet, dass er es nicht gewesen ist." Beides zulässige Formen der indirekten Rede.

Comment: Um das Verb geht es in der Frage, also wechselt man es nicht ohne Not in den Beispielen aus.

Comment: Kommentare sind nicht zur Beantwortung der Frage bestimmt. Für den Zweck wird die Antwort bearbeitet.

Answer (score 3):

"Sei" ist der Konjunktiv Präsens von "sein": *ich sei, du seiest, er sei,
wir seien, ihr seiet, sie seien.*