# "Konjunktiv der Annahme"

Tags: subjunctive

In mathematischen Lehrbüchern auf Universitätsniveau findet sich oft der Konjunktiv I in Sätzen wir z.B.

"**Sei** f eine dreifach differenzierbare Funktion und **habe** im Intervall I keine Nullstellen."

In der Schule würde der selbe Satz üblichererweise wie folgt formuliert werden:

"f **ist** eine differenzierbare Funktion und **hat** im Intervall I keine Nullstellen."

- Welche der beiden Varianten ist korrekt?
- Falls die erste korrekt ist: Gibt es einen Fachausdruck für diese Verwendung des Konjunktiv?

Mein Sprachgefühl sagt mir, dass wir zwischen Faktum (A) (Verwendung im zweiten Beispiel), einer bloßen Annahme (B) (erstes Beispiel) und einer Annahme, von der wir schon wissen, dass sie falsch ist (C), unterscheiden müssen. Dies spiegelt sich auch in der Alltagssprache wieder, z.B.

(A): "Paul hat rote Haare" (Faktum)
(B): "Paul habe rote Haare" (Annahme, dass ein unbekannter "Paul" rote Haare habe)
(C): "Paul hätte rote Haare" (Ein konkreter Paul hat keine roten Haare, es wird aber angenommen, dass er welche hätte).

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1756

Comment: Ich war nie ein Genie in Mathe, aber wenn ich mich recht entsinne, ging es mit "Sei f..." los, gefolgt von "...so gilt..." und "...daraus folgt..." und das steht dann im Indikativ. Am Anfang ist also eine Annahme, die wir als Voraussetzung haben, daher Konjunktiv, und danach haben wir resultierende Fakten, also Indikativ. Folglich sind deine beiden Sätze richtig, vorausgesetzt der erste ist die Annahme und der zweite die Folge.

Comment: Kannst Du zu dem Satz, von dem Du meinst, er würde in der Schule verwandt, ein Beispiel mit mehr Kontext angeben?

Comment: Das Problem ist, dass es sich hier gar nicht um den Konjunktiv, sondern um den Imperativ handelt.

Comment: Die zweite Konstruktion ist problematisch, da die Rechtschreibung erfordert, f groß zu schreiben, andererseits die Konventionen i.d. Mathematik sehr streng sind, was die Schreibung von Bezeichnern betrifft. "Ist f eine …  Funktion" kann aber als Frage aufgefasst werden. "Eine … Funktion f hat im Intervall …" würde aber auch ohne "sei" auskommen. Vielleicht spielten solch pragmatische Überlegungen eine Rolle. Einen Grund das "sei" zu meiden, sehe ich aber nicht.

Answer (score 6):

**Welche der beiden Varianten ist korrekt?**

Beide sind korrekt, aber sie drücken nicht dasselbe aus.

- "*f* ist eine Funktion..." ist eine Tatsachenaussage.
- "Sei *f* eine Funktion..." ist eigentlich eine Befehlsform, aber die Anweisung richtet sich nicht an die Schüler, sondern an eine dritte Instanz. Im Beispiel ist es die Funktion *f*, die bestimmte Eigenschaften haben soll.

**Gibt es einen Fachbegriff für diese Verwendung des Konjunktivs?**

Ich würde sagen ja, es handelt sich um ein Beispiel für den [Jussiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jussiv).
Der Jussiv ist der Modus des Verbs, der „Befehle“ an eine „nicht anwesende Person“ (also an eine Drittperson) ausdrückt. Auf Deutsch verwendet man dazu entweder den Konjunktiv I:

> Man nehme zwei Eier.

Oder man verwendet das modale Hilfsverb „sollen“.

Die folgende Formulierung der mathematische Aufgabe ist daher gleichbedeutend und etwas näher an der Umgangssprache:

> *f* soll eine dreifach differenzierbare Funktion sein und im Intervall *I* keine Nullstellen haben.

Comment: +1 für den *Jussiv*

Comment: Hm. In meinem gewählten Kontext soll aber beide Male dasselbe ausgedrückt werden. Der Name f für die Funktion soll beide Male mit diesem Satz neu eingeführt werden. Somit sehe ich die Jussiv-Variante als korrekt an, wenn beide Varianten nicht dasselbe ausdrücken. Die erste Variante wäre z.B. korrekt, wenn vorher schon der Name f z.B. inklusive einer konkreten Zuordnungsvorschrift eingeführt worden wäre (eine gegebene Zuordnung mit dem Namen f kann ja eine Funktion sein oder auch nicht, je nachdem, ob es eine eindeutige Zuordnung ist oder nicht).

Comment: Geht es vielleicht gar nicht so sehr um die Grammatik, sondern eher um den Stil? Ich kann mir vorstellen, dass Schüler (je nach Stufe) Mühe haben, die Formulierung im Konjunktiv zu verstehen, und dass man darum den Indikativ bevorzugt. Geht es eventuell darum, wie man auszudrücken kann, dass es sich um ein Annahme/Forderung handelt, und nicht um eine Gesetzmässigkeit? Es gibt es viele Möglichkeiten ("Angenommen, f ist eine dreifach differenzierbare Funktion ..."), und vielleicht wird es ja schon aus dem Kontext klar. Kannst du eventuell die Frage präzisieren?

Comment: In einem Mathe-Skript von Markus Junker von der [Uni Freiburg](https://home.mathematik.uni-freiburg.de/junker/skripte/Vorkurs-WS22.pdf) wird in einer Fußnote (Seite 11 unten) davon gesprochen, dass es wohl eher ein Optativ sei

Answer (score 4):

Ob beide Varianten richtig sind, weiß ich nicht.

In der Mathematik ist es aber meines Wissens so, dass die beiden Sätze nicht dieselbe Bedeutung haben:

Der Indikativ wird verwendet, wenn eine Tatsache aus einem anderen Satz folgt.

Der Konjunktiv wird hingegen verwendet, wenn der Satz selbst quasi eine "Forderung" z.B. an die Auswahl einer Funktion darstellt.

Beispiel:

> Die Funktion f **sei** eine Funktion, deren Funktionswerte allesamt positiv sind.
>
> Dann **ist** f eine Funktion, die keine Nullstellen aufweist.

Answer (score 1):

Für mathematische Gedankenspiele "Wir denken uns, dass folgende Situation bestehen könnte" wird der Konjunktiv verwendet, also "Sei ... und habe ...".

Fakten werden mit "... ist ... hat" beschrieben.

Das ist in der mathematischen Fachsprache so festgelegt.