# Konjunktiv I in der Mathematik

Tags: subjunctive, mathematics, auxiliary-verb

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
>   *http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1756*

In mathematischen Beweisen oder Definitionen wird häufig der Konjunktiv I verwendet, z.B.:

> Definition: **Sei *X* eine endliche Menge** Boolescher Variablen. Eine Wahrheitsbelegung für *X* ist eine Funktion *T*: *X*→{true,false}. Wir erweitern *T* auf die Menge *L*:=*X̄* ∪ {*x̄*: *x*∈*X*} der Literale über *X*, indem wir *T*(*x̄*) :=true genau dann setzen, wenn *T*(*x*) = false.

Könnte jemand erklären, weshalb hier der Konjunktiv I benutzt wird? Es geht ja nicht um eine indirekte Rede.
Würde *wäre* statt *sei* hier auch gehen?

Comment: Answered in English here: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1756/why-use-konjunktiv-i-in-mathematics

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf As this question is in German and the other one in English according to meta https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/807/what-to-do-with-duplicate-questions-in-another-language/809#809 it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Hier scheint sich jeder sicher zu sein, dass das Konjunktiv ist. Ich kenne keinen Grund, warum das kein Imperativ an die 3. Person/Jussiv sein sollte ("man nehme ...")

Comment: @tofro https://german.stackexchange.com/a/1759/3237

Comment: @tofro, Wikipedia sagt: "Im Deutschen wird der Jussiv mit dem Konjunktiv I abgebildet." So there's that.

Comment: @CarstenS Nur weil das da steht - Das sieht nur so aus. Der Jussiv hat nichts mit dem ursprünglichen Zweck des Konjunktivs zu tun, sondern kommt eher aus der Mode, dass man sich früher in der 3. Person angeredet hat (*bring(e) er mir den Wein") - Da sehe ich keinen Konjunktiv.

Comment: @tofro, da ich kein Grammatiker bin, finde ich die Frage, ob man von einem Modus mit zwei verschiedenen Verwendungen oder von zwei Modi, die in allen Formen übereinstimmen, recht uninteressant.

Comment: @tofro, übrigens haben wir immer noch: „Bringen Sie mir den Wein!“  Das wird heute wohl als Imperativ klassifiziert, ist von der Form her aber auch dritte Person.

Comment: @CarstenS Wenn du "Bringen Sie mir den Wein" als Imperativ (und ncht als Indikativ) klassifizierst, musst du auch "Bringe er mir den Wein" als Imperativ (und nicht als Konjunktiv) klassifizieren. Das ist genau das, was ich meine.

Comment: @tofro Nein, muss er nicht. Nach allgemeiner Auffassung gibt es den Imperativ im Singular: "Bring(e) ..." und im Plural: "Bringen Sie ...". Weitere Formen sind nicht anerkannt, demnach ist "Er bringe..." kein Imperativ und kann daher nur Konjunktiv I sein.

Comment: Ergänzung: Es gibt natürlich noch den Imperativ Plural "Bringt ..."

Answer (score 3):

## Konjunktiv I in selbständigen Sätzen

Die Frage weist schon auf die Quelle der Irritation hin:

> Könnte jemand erklären, weshalb hier der Konjunktiv I benutzt wird? Es geht ja nicht um eine indirekte Rede.

Wir kennen den Konjunktiv I als Mittel zur Redewiedergabe in eingebetteten Sätzen. Wenn er in dieser Funktion in einem selbständigen Satz auftritt, ist die Einleitung dazugedacht.

> Sie hat sich über mich beim Chef beschwert. <Sie sagte> ich **sei** zu langsam.

Etwas in Vergessenheit geraten ist der Konjunktiv I in selbständigen Sätzen. Hier bezeichnet er einen Wunsch oder eine Aufforderung.

> Er **lebe** hoch!
>   Man **erwarte** nicht, daß ich mit einer förmlichen Erklärung des Daseins den Anfang machen werde.  (*Kant*)

Diese Verwendung ist zunehmend auf wenige Verben beschränkt. Gerne wird *mögen* benutzt.

> Man **möge** es mir verzeihen, daß … (*statt*: man verzeihe …)
>   Niemand **möge** sich einreden … (*statt*: Niemand rede sich ein …)

Während Konjunktiv I und II in abhängigen Sätzen beide zur Redewiedergabe verwendet werden, also zu einem gewissen Grad austauschbar sind, gilt diese Austauschbarkeit in selbständigen Sätzen nicht. Der Konjunktiv II hat hier seine eigene Aufgabe:

> **Wärst** du doch nur bei mir! (*Exklamativ, kontrafaktisch*)
>   Du **wärst** nicht der Erste, der das versucht. (*verstecktes kontrafaktisches Konditional*)
>   ~Wenn du das versuchen würdest, wärst du nicht der Erste.

Den "Mathesätzen" *sei x eine natürliche Zahl* fehlt das Kontrafaktische. Der Konjunktiv I schließt hier die Verwirklichung nicht aus, sondern ein.

> Gott **sei** mit dir!

## Abgrenzung zum Imperativ

Das Deutsche kennt die Modi **Indikativ** und **Konjunktiv**. Den **Imperativ** stellt man am besten als Halbmodus neben diese beiden, da er nicht nach Tempus differenziert und auf die 2. Person beschränkt ist. Formell und funktional stehen der 
Konjunktiv I in selbständigen Sätzen und der Imperativ sich nahe. Formell wegen der weitgehenden Übereinstimmung von 1./3. Sg. Präs. Konj. und Imperativ Sg. *(sei*, *bleib(e)*, *leb(e))* und der Verwendung der 3. Pl. Präs. Konj. *seien* in Aufforderungssätzen mit der Distanzform *Sie*. Funktional wegen Paaren wie dem folgenden:

> Wer Interesse hat, der **sage** bitte Bescheid! (*Konjunktiv*)
>   **Sagt** doch Bescheid, wenn ihr Interesse habt! (*Imperativ*)

Hier zeigt sich, daß man **Verbmodus** und **Satzmodus** auseinanderhalten muß: Trotz der unterschiedlichen Verbmodi ist der Satzmodus der gleiche, nämlich der einer Aufforderung.

Daß es sich bei dem *sei* in Mathesätzen nicht um einen Imperativ handelt und bei den Sätzen nicht um Aufforderungen, erkennt man an folgenden Merkmalen:

1. Es kann ein **Vorfeld-*es*** stehen.

> **Es** sei x eine natürliche Zahl.
>   **Es** lebe der König!
>   *Es seien Sie so nett und bringen mir noch einen Kaffee.
>   *Es bleiben Sie sitzen!

2. Die Partikel **doch** kann nicht stehen.

> *Sei x doch eine natürliche Zahl.
>   *Der König lebe doch hoch!
>   Seien Sie **doch** so nett und bringen mir noch einen Kaffee.
>   Bleiben Sie **doch** sitzen!

3. Die Aufforderung verlangt einen geeigneten Adressaten. Dieser ist das Subjekt. Bei einem Wunsch richtet man sich dagegen nicht unbedingt an das Subjekt. Im ersten der beiden folgenden Beispiele ist der Teufel nicht notwendigerweise als anwesend gedacht und nicht angesprochen.

> **Der Teufel** hole ihn. (*Konjunktiv, Wunsch*, Teufel *nicht Adressat*)
>   ≠ **O Teufel**, hol(e) ihn! (*Imperativ, Aufforderung*, Teufel *Adressat*)

Für mich ist es unvorstellbar, daß eine Variable angesprochen werden soll. Die Mathesätze gehören also in die gleiche Kategorie wie das erste Beispiel. In den Fällen, in denen mit dem Konjunktiv eine Aufforderung zum Ausdruck gebracht wird, ist das Subjekt der Adressat, anwesend und angesprochen:

> Sei **Er** kein schellenlauter Tor!

## Optativ? Jussiv?

Es gibt keinen Grund, einen der beiden Begriffe zur Beantwortung der Frage heranzuziehen. Das Indogermanische hatte den **Optativ** als Modus. Seine Funktion war, Wünsche auszudrücken. Daher liegt es dem historischen Sprachwissenschaftler nahe, von einer **optativen Funktion** des Konjunktivs zu sprechen, wenn er einen Wunsch ausdrückt. Man muß aber Modus und Funktion immer auseinanderhalten. Der Begriff **Jussiv** bezeichnet nur eine Funktion und keine Verbform.

Man kann das mit den Begriffen *Genitiv* (Form eines Nomens) vs. *Genitivus subjectivus* (eine Funktion des Genitivs) vergleichen.

Answer (score 2):

In der englischsprachigen Antwort die oben verlinkt ist wird dieses Konstrukt als [Optativ](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optativ) bezeichnet. Dies kann man so sehen, allerdings würde ich es eher als [**Jussiv**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jussiv) bezeichnen.

Beide werden mit dem Konkunktiv I gebildet und während der Optativ einen **Wunsch** darstellt ist der Jussiv ein **Befehl**. Den Jussiv findet man in Ausdrücken wie

> Gott erhalte Franz den Kaiser.
>
> Man höre und staune.

oder in Rezepten als

> Man nehme drei Eier ...

oder eben in

> Sei X eine endliche Menge Boolescher Variablen.

---

Warum kein Imperativ?

In der Regel wird der Imperativ mit der 2. Person gebildet, der Jussiv dagegen ist ein Befehl an die 3. grammatische Person, was hier der Fall ist (oder wenn man es im Beispiel doch als Wunsch ansieht wäre es ein Optativ). Zwar gibt es, wie von Hubert erwähnt, die altertümliche Anrede-Form "Sei Er/Sie doch leise", allerdings halte ich dies für hier nicht zutreffend (da keine Anrede).